# TFVC to Git Mirroring (No Migration)

Tags: git, tfs, tfvc

I am looking for a mirroring solution for **TFVC** and **Git**.

I need to have developers continue using TFVC, but I want TFVC content to be mirrored (real-time preferably) to remote Git repositories.

This is **not** a migration and I don't want developers to have to use client-side tools for this. This can be a one-way mirroring process (TFVC --> Git).

Comment: Have a look to https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs You could add the git-tfs command inside a TFS build.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you can [Map TFVC actions to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/concepts/mapping-my-tfvc-actions-to-git?tabs=command-line) or [Import repositories from TFVC to Git](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/git/import-from-tfvc) if you are using TFS 2017 or later version.

But for the mirror, you need to sync the content between TFVC and Git, real-time is impossible, however you can try to run scripts in CI ([continuous integration](https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/vsts/build-release/apps/windows/dot-net?tabs=vsts#set-up-continuous-integration)) build to get the latest changes from TFVC and transfer them to local Git repository, then commit the changes and push to the remote Git repo.

To do that you need to use the [git-tfs](https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs) tool, it's a bridge tool to be able to import a TFVC history in a git repository. Reference this thread : [Use git with git-tfs for backing up TFVC on Visual Studio Team Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36127563/use-git-with-git-tfs-for-backing-up-tfvc-on-visual-studio-team-services). And this article may helps : [MIGRATING FROM TFVC TO GIT](https://blog.cellenza.com/devops/migrating-from-tfvc-to-git/)

You can change From TFVC to Git if possible, then you can sync the contents bewteen two Git repositories more smoothly. Refer to [Keep Git repository in sync between VSTS / TFS and Git](http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2016/10/22/keep-git-repository-in-sync-between-vsts-tfs-and-git/) for details.

Comment: @Cody Schilke Have you resolved the issue? any update?